# Excel 2010: VLOOKUP Function

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have two sheets namely:

1. `Sheet1`
2. `Sheet2`

The following data which sheets contain.

**Sheet1**:

```
  A         B           C            D
-----------------------------------------
Emp_ID  Emp_Name    Str_Date    End_Date
1         EmpA      1/1/2010    1/1/2011
1         EmpA      1/2/2010    1/2/2011
1         EmpA      1/3/2010    1/3/2011
1         EmpA      1/4/2010    1/4/2011
2         EmpB      1/5/2010    1/5/2011
2         EmpB      1/6/2010    1/6/2011
2         EmpB      1/7/2010    1/7/2011
2         EmpB      1/8/2010    1/8/2011
3         EmpC      1/9/2010    1/9/2011
3         EmpC      1/10/2010   1/10/2011
3         EmpC      1/11/2010   1/11/2011
3         EmpC      1/12/2010   1/12/2011
```

**Sheet2**:

```
   A      B        C
------------------------
Dept_ID Emp_ID  Emp_Name
111     1   
222     2   
333     3   
444     4   
555     5   
666     6
```

**Note**: I want to print the employee name in the second sheet which should match the employeeID from `sheet1`. If the employeeID doesn't match then it should print empty cell.

## My try:

I have written the following VLOOKUP Function in the `sheet2` below the column Emp_Name.

**Function**:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet1!A4:B15,2),"")
```

**Getting Output**:

```
   A      B        C
------------------------
Dept_ID Emp_ID  Emp_Name
111     1       EmpA
222     2       EmpB
333     3       EmpC
444     4       EmpC
555     5       EmpC
666     6       EmpC
```

**Expected Result**:

```
   A      B        C
------------------------
Dept_ID Emp_ID  Emp_Name
111     1       EmpA
222     2       EmpB
333     3       EmpC
444     4       
555     5       
666     6
```

**Note**: In the expected result the employeeID 4, 5, 6 don't have entries in the `sheet1` so the result should be empty cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try an exact match formula, so use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet1!A4:B15,2,0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet1!A$4:B$15,2,0),"") can be reliably copied from cell to cell without shifting the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is also good.

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet1!A4:B15,2),"")

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for those seeing it now: **Don't use `VLOOKUP`.**

To my knowledge, there is NEVER a situation where VLOOKUP would be the best option.

`INDEX/MATCH` is better in literally every way.

- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is faster. When you have hundreds or thousands of formulas, you can often speed up a workbook drastically simply by swapping out all of the `VLOOKUP`s.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is more versatile. It can work on rows or columns and your lookup range can be anywhere. You can even lookup a value in a 2D table using `INDEX`/`MATCH`/`MATCH`.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is more stable. Moving or re-ordering columns doesn't break your formulas.
- `INDEX`/`MATCH` is easier to use. It may look confusing if you are used to `VLOOKUP`, but once you understand it, it is actually easier to use because you can directly reference the ranges, rather than counting the number of columns across.

So, the `INDEX/MATCH` version of the formula would be:

```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$4:$C$15,MATCH(B4,Sheet1!$B$4:$B$15,0)),"")
```